# R: Loaded tweets structure is untidy when str()

Tags: r, string, tweets

Differently from my collegue, after I load the tweets with R and I try to see the structure with str() the data appears in a messy way with a lot of dots, rather than being organized as a table, which is what happens with my collegue's computer, even if the codes are the same. I can't understand what is the problem, we have the same packages installed and the same R version.

```
library(rtweet) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr) 
library(tibble) 
library(tidytext) 
library(stringr)
 library(stringi) 
library(igraph) 
library(ggraph) 
library(readr) 
library(lubridate) 
library(zoo) 

appname <- "" 
key <- "" 
secret <- "" 
twitter_token <- create_token( app = "", consumer_key = "", consumer_secret = "", access_token = "", access_secret = "") 

tweets <- search_tweets(q = "#water + #climatechange", n = 10000, lang = "en", include_rts = FALSE) 
str(tweets)


  
     .. ..$ media        :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  11 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id             : num 1.57e+18
  .. .. ..$ id_str         : chr "1573815153484759040"
  .. .. ..$ indices        :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. .. .. ..$ start: int 241
  .. .. .. .. ..$ end  : int 264
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
  .. .. ..$ media_url      : chr "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/FddQiy2WAAAl59Q.jpg"
  .. .. ..$ media_url_https: chr "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FddQiy2WAAAl59Q.jpg"
  .. .. ..$ url            : chr "https
  .. .. ..$ display_url    : chr "pic.twitter.com/iFJTkF1S9S"
  .. .. ..$ expanded_url   : chr "https://twitter.com/TreeBanker/status/1573815156768968706/photo/1"
  .. .. ..$ type           : chr "photo"
  .. .. ..$ sizes          :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. .. .. .. ..$ w     : int [1:4] 1096 680 150 1096
  .. .. .. .. ..$ h     : int [1:4] 733 455 150 733
  .. .. .. .. ..$ resize: chr [1:4] "fit" "fit" "crop" "fit"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ type  : chr [1:4] "large" "small" "thumb" "medium"
  .. .. ..$ ext_alt_text   : logi NA
  ..$ :List of 5

  .. ..$ media        :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  11 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id             : num 1.57e+18
  .. .. ..$ id_str         : chr "1573815153484759040"
  .. .. ..$ indices        :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you used to get this result? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ` library(rtweet)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

appname <- ""
key <- ""
secret <- ""

twitter_token <- create_token(
  app = "",
  consumer_key = "",
  consumer_secret = "",
  access_token = "",
  access_secret = "")

 tweets <- search_tweets(q = "#water + #climatechange", n = 10000,
                        lang = "en",
                        include_rts = FALSE)
str(tweets)`